# Django secret key

Tags: django

I am new to django. I have created a test code and it has the secret key in folder `app/settings.py`. It mentions `# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!`

But I also need to share the code with other developers for additional help so they are aware of the secret key now which was generated when the project was first created.

Can I just change the characters in the secret key before I build for production?

Comment: Normally you define two `settings.py`: one *secret* one for production, and one you use for development. The real `SECRET_KEY` normally is only used in the secret file in production.

Comment: Have a look at `python-decouple`.  Here's a great blog post on it - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html